# SetOptions not working with PlotStyle option in GraphPlot

Tags: plotting, graphs-and-networks

While both

```
GraphPlot[graph,PlotStyle->Orange]
```

and,

```
SetOptions[Plot,PlotStyle->Orange];Plot[x^2,{x,0,1}]
```

works.

```
SetOptions[GraphPlot,PlotStyle-> Orange];GraphPlot[graph]
```

does not work.

I saw that in the case of Plot sometimes setting PlotTheme->None can work but

```
SetOptions[GraphPlot,PlotTheme-> None]
```

did not help with GraphPlot.

I can just add manually the PlotStyle option each time but I am a bit curious as to what option is overriding the PlotStyle option if anyone happens to know.

Comment: Please pose an example.

Comment: I would consider this a bug. You should contact Wolfram directly. As a workaround, you can set `SetOptions[Graph, EdgeStyle -> Orange, VertexStyle -> Orange]` to achieve the same.

Comment: @Szabolcs that seems to work for graphs given in terms of a list of edges like Graph[{1 \[UndirectedEdge] 2, 2 \[UndirectedEdge] 3, 
  3 \[UndirectedEdge] 1}] but it does not seem to work for graphs like RandomGraph or the outputs that I get from my program that has options like edge labels, vertex labels and a graph layout. I guess the best solution would be to just define a personal graph function like graphplot=GraphPlot[#,PlotStyle->Orange] &